# is there any way to force the accelerometer to update on a regular time interval?

Tags: android, accelerometer, average

Would it be possible say, to get the accelerometer to update 50 times a second? the reason I want to do this is is that I want to let the accelerometer run, collect all of the different values it records and then return an average.

I initially tried to just collect all of the different values

```
 yAverage = yAverage + new y;
```

and then divide it by a counter that recorded the amount of different recordings.

```
 counter++;
```

both lines of code are in the "onSensorChanged" method and will always execute together (as in, if one executes the other will also execute without fail)

However the results I am getting are very inconsistent. if I have the phone lying flat on the table it will calculate almost random different values for the average even though the sensor value never changes and there for should always return the same.

Is there a better way to calculate the average?

I dont know if it matters but I am using floats to store the recorded values and doing the calculations.

***Responce to Sherif:***
well there isnt really that much code in it, I have 3 float values that get the values from the acclerometer like so:

```
 y=event.values[1];
```

and it is located inside the "onSensorChanged" method inside the SensorEventListener.

I suppose the pseudo code would go like this:

```
 float yAverage = 0

 onSensorChanged{
    float y = event.values[1];
    if (y < 0){
       y = y * -1;
    }
    yAverage = yAverage + y;
    counter++;
 }
```

and then in another method it calculates;

```
 yAverage = yAverage / counter;
```

It then get's printed to the screen

it's not a complicated method but I just can't figure out why it is so inaccurate.

Comment: maybe you could show us some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea if it is an execution error but I think it is a logical error

```
SensorManager mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
Sensor mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    float y = event.values[1];
    if (y < 0){
        y = y * -1;
    }
yAverage = yAverage + y;
counter++; 
}
```

Summary:

- make sure yAverage is global
- make sure you're using TYPE_ACCELEROMETER
- Don't forget that when put on a table you will get high values for value[1] due to gravity and Normal

Comment: ah dammit yeah i accidentally wrote that piece of code wrong, the "yAverage" object is not defined in the onSensorChanged method, it is defined in another class an I am accessing it statically. The actuall code in my program is the same as the way that you have it. I will edit it now

Comment: Can you please explain "the results are very inconsistent". example?

Comment: well if i leave the phone flat on the table the accelerometer value is (more or less) comstant it tends to fluctuate in the .001 area. but it will generally keep a solid 9.8 value. So obviously if it is constantly adding 9.8 to the average value and counting every time that it does it should just divide down to 9.8 again. but sometimes it will give values like 0.2 or 0.3 or 5.0 or 6.0 or even 13.0 14.0 but the phone is not moving at all :S

Comment: yes the only thing that I have different is that I have SENSOR_DELAY_UI which is the slowest update. Is there any way to set the SENSOR_DELAY to be a fixed value?

Comment: try registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, 0);

Comment: I found the reason why the values were fulctuating wildly. The counter was not resetting to 0 when I stopped the app as I had only declared it and not actually initiallised it to 0. Still some accuracy issues so I am looking into those now. I will select your answer as it was trying your advice that led me to spot the problem. I will also look into the registerListener. Thanks again for all your help